# Concatenar consulta en Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual si me muestra la consulta

```
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel)tblPacientes.getModel();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT V.idViaje, V.FechaAlta, V.folio, UCASE(V.Cliente), V.total, V.importe AS 'Cliente' FROM merca V LEFT JOIN clientes C ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC");
        rs.first();
        do{
            String[] fila = {rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),"$"+rs.getString(5),"$"+rs.getString(6)};
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }while(rs.next());   
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConsultaPaciente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Este es el ejemplo funcionando, si le doy clic en el botón **Buscar** me muestra todos los registros hasta ahí todo bien, pero como concateno para que me busque lo que ponga en **folio** *(tfFolio)* y/o **asegurado** *(tfAsegurado)*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es un botón que diga "Buscar" y ese debería de ir a consultar a la mismas tablas pero con los filtros de Folio y Asegurado.
Por ejemplo

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT V.idViaje, V.FechaAlta, V.folio, 
               UCASE(V.Cliente), V.total, V.importe AS 'Cliente' FROM merca 
               V LEFT JOIN clientes C ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente <b>WHERE 
               V.folio = "+variableFolio+" OR asegurado = 
               "+variableAsegurado+"</b> ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC");
```

Observa que agrege la condición

1. `WHERE v.folio =` //para buscar por folio
2. el operdor `OR` para que regrese un resultado ya sea por folio o asegurado
3. `asegurado =` //para buscar también por asegurado (no se en que tabla tengas este dato)

*Nota: considero que en lugar de ser un operador `=` sea un operador `LIKE`
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Por favor cuando insertes código no uses las etiquetas **<pre>**, pues no dan un formato adecuado, selecciona tu código y presiona `ctrl + k` o selecciona tu código y presiona el ícono `{}`

Comment: no utilice las etiquetas <pre>

Comment: error mío me refería a las etiquetas **code**

Comment: Que tal amigo, si tengo el boton "Buscar" si te fijas en la imagen hasta abajo de la tabla ahi esta, me salio el siguiente error con la query que me brindaste (modifique las variables por las mias) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[,206,56,72x28,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignment' at line 1

Comment: no lo había visto!! ... pero ahí debes modificar tu consulta... agregar las 2 condiciones... espero te haya sido útil.